# Image src is not completely scraped.(../../../images/stat/popolazione.jpg)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am using the following code and I am unable to get complete src of image.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def statistics(url):
    resp = get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")

    reqTable = soup.find('table', class_ = 'tabwrap')
    images = reqTable.findAll('img')

    for img in images:
        print(img['src'])

statistics('http://www.comuni-italiani.it/084/001/statistiche/')
```

output: 
[image]

This is image src i want to scrape:

Link to website: http://www.comuni-italiani.it/084/001/statistiche/

I want to get this Popolazione number out of the image src so that's why I need that src so i can split and get that number 59.605

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to get the numbers available in those image links:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_image_links(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    for img in soup.select('table.tabwrap img[src*="d_fnote_title"]'):
        item_num = img['src'].split("h|")[1].split("|")[0]
        print(item_num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = 'http://www.comuni-italiani.it/084/001/statistiche/'
    get_image_links(link)
```

Comment: I want to get this Popolazione number out of the image src so that's why I need that src so i can split and get that number 59.605

Comment: I am getting this output: http://www.comuni-italiani.it/images/stat/famiglia.jpg

But i want : http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_fnote_title&chld=sticky_y|1|004400|h|59.605|Popolazione|2016